# How to exclude post from being queried based on custom meta value

Tags: php, custom-field, query-posts

I am building a reviewing system for user-submitted posts on my website. I have a page called **page-review.php** which displays the oldest post of the "pending review" category. This is to ensure that every user-submission gets reviewed. There is only one post displayed on this page at a time.

```
$review_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'cat' => 22,
);

$review_query = new WP_Query($review_args);
```

After a post has been reviewed a new custom meta tag will be added to the post called **reviewed_by**. This meta tag contains an array of user IDs that have reviewed this post.

How do I make it so that my query checks if the custom meta **reviewed_by** has the current user's ID in it? And if it does find it in the **reviewed_by** array then it will show the next oldest post that doesn't have the user's ID in the custom meta.

UPDATE:

I still can't seem to get it working. The content in **reviewed_by** looks like the following (it's an array converted to a string I believe)

```
a:1:{i:0;i:34;}
```

This is an array where my user_id is 34.

```
$review_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'cat' => 22,
    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' =>'reviewed_by',
                            'value' => $current_user_id,
                            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
                        )
                    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the codex for [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you should be able to tack on some meta related arguments to your args array (this is untested):

```
$review_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'cat' => 22,
    'meta_query' => array(
                        'key'=>'reviewed_by',
                        'value'=> $reviewed_by_array,
                        'compare'=> 'NOT IN'
                    )
);

$review_query = new WP_Query($review_args);
```

Comment: I have tried this with some edited code (as the code you provided wasn't complete) but I still cannot seem to get it working. I think it has to do with the 'compare' part although I am not entirely sure. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a different approach which is a lot easier. I created a new custom user_meta called **review_completed**. This user_meta contains an Array of the post IDs of the submissions that they have reviewed.

Then I simply added a new line to my **review_args** as seen below.

```
$user_review_completed = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'review_completed', true);

$review_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'cat' => 22,
    'post__not_in' => $user_review_completed
);
```